# What happens to access rights when files are moved to a windows partition

Tags: permissions

im a computer science student and had this question on a test.
What access rights will a linux file have after it first has been moved to a disk formated for Windows and then moved back to the linux partition.

could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

normally if you have created a text file under root user. It will get created with rw permission. After moving to windows and recopying it back to linux won't change the properties.

**ls -lh** will list the permission as

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 32 Oct 28 06:21 test.txt (both before and after)
```